Script to automatically update Chrome and ChromeDriver Ubuntu
We have several Ubuntu self-hosted VMs on Azure. They run automated test pipelines and are much more efficient than their Windows counterparts.
However, the manual process for updating the frequent Chrome and ChromeDriver releases IS a real pain!
Anyone have a (Python) script to automate this process please?
Thanks
